# Conditional setting of certain fields in a builder

Tags: java, conditional-statements, builder

I have a legacy Java class with a builder - I can't change this class.

Some of the setters of the builder are throwing an exception on `null` input:

```
     public Cat.Builder setOwnerName(String value) {
        if (value == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        } else {
            this.ownerName = value;
            this.onChanged();
            return this;
        }
     }
```

I'm trying to create that `Cat` from another class - using an external object that may, or may not, have a `null` value in the relevant field:

```
  Cat cat = Cat.newBuilder()
            .setXYZ("XYZ")
            .setOwnerName(inputFromUser.getOwnerName())
            .build();
```

And since the `inputFromUser.getOwnerName()` is sometimes `null`, the builder throws an exception.

I'm trying to find an elegant way to conditionally set or not the `ownerName` (or any other of the non-null fields).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Cat.Builder builder = Cat.newBuilder()
    .setXYZ("XYZ");
Optional.ofNullable(inputFromUser.getOwnerName())
    .ifPresent(builder::setOwnerName);
// repeat above statement for all optional fields
Cat cat = builder.build();
```

Comment: This is a nice elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use call chaining to invoke a builder:

```
Cat.Builder catBuilder = Cat.newBuilder();
catBuilder.setXYZ("XYZ");
catBuilder.setOwnerName(inputFromUser.getOwnerName());
Cat cat = catBuilder.build();
```

(You *probably* don't. There's no requirement for a Builder method to return itself, but it would be a little unusual if it didn't).

So, write it like this, and put a conditional where needed.

```
Cat.Builder catBuilder = Cat.newBuilder();
catBuilder.setXYZ("XYZ")
if (inputFromUser.getOwnerName() != null) {
  catBuilder.setOwnerName(inputFromUser.getOwnerName());
}
Cat cat = catBuilder.build();
```

---

If you wanted to be a bit more functional, you could write a method like:

```
<T> void consumeIfNonNull(@Nullable T value, Consumer<? super T> consumer) {
  if (value != null) consumer.accept(value);
}
```

and then do:

```
consumeIfNonNull(inputFromUser.getOwnerName(), catBuilder::setOwnerName);
```

I think this is neater at the call site than using an `Optional`, but to each their own.